# VB.net Object reference not set error

Tags: vb.net

So I am getting this error Object Reference not set to an instance of an object. for some reason when I run it image = nothing which is causing rng = code to get this error.

```
Dim image As Excel.Shape
        ' This sets a reference to the image/end indactor.
        image = oSheet.Shapes(oSheet.Shapes.Count)

        ' This sets up the range we are going to want to cut/copy over.
        rng = oSheet.Range("A1", oSheet.Cells(image.TopLeftCell.Row + 3, 8))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: -1 shape does not work an i don't believe this a duplicate

Comment: `when I run it image = nothing` is the **definition** of a NullReferenceException an Object Reference (image) is not set to an instance of an object. work out why image is Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You should always check for potential errors - especially when dealing with things like Excel!

```
Dim image As Excel.Shape
' This sets a reference to the image/end indactor.
image = oSheet.Shapes(oSheet.Shapes.Count)

If image IsNot Nothing Then
    ' This sets up the range we are going to want to cut/copy over.
    rng = oSheet.Range("A1", oSheet.Cells(image.TopLeftCell.Row + 3, 8))
Else
    Throw New Exception("There are no shapes on the sheet 'oSheet'.")
End If
```

That of course assumes oSheet is not Nothing as well.  I hope that helps you on your way.